# Recommended change for Intel RST documentation

Tags: raid, documentation

I'm not sure if this is the best platform to mention this, but the method for switching to AHCI described in the [Intel RST documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/) is unnecessarily complicated. Setting the registry keys is always a fraught process, and is sometimes impossible to do reliably, even with administrator access. (I had major trouble with it since I tried to do it using a network user account.) There are much simpler and more foolproof ways of achieving the same thing, see [here](https://support.thinkcritical.com/kb/articles/switch-windows-10-from-raid-ide-to-ahci) for instance. Could the guide be updated with such a simpler method?

Comment: This (AskUbuntu) is not the right platform. Try clicking on "Contribute" in the top row of the document.

Comment: Can you provide a simpler method?

Answer (score 0):

Many **help**.ubuntu.com pages are immutable. They are not a wiki and cannot be directly edited.

- Don't be confused: Pages at **wiki**.ubuntu.com look similar, and **are** a wiki and can be edited by any Ubuntu Member. Look at the subdomain ('help' vs 'wiki') to be sure which you are looking at.

However, help.ubuntu.com pages usually pull from source at discourse.ubuntu.com. (In your case, https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347). You can post to that thread.

- Registration for discourse.ubuntu.com is required.
- You might need to participate in a thread or two to unlock your ability to post.
- The documentation threads are for specific, detailed change recommendations only: *"Change 'XYZ' to 'ABC' because of reason GHI"*. Generic *hey-update-this* or vague posts or misplaced support requests may be removed by moderators.